# Why grunt appears under `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`?

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js, package.json

After running `sails new myProject` a new sails project is created under `myProject` directory. Why grunt libraries appear under the `dependencies` section instead of `devDependencies` in `package.json`?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I think it is because grunt tasks still run while the application is going. This may be to help out when you have a server up and running, want to add in a couple of `/assets/ folder and still get them linked appropriately. Again, no idea.

Comment: This isn't really a question for SO as it is simply how the `sails` CLI works. You should post an issue on their GitHub page if you think it is a mistake.

Comment: Hey @jakerella, I kind of agree on that. The thing is that I went to their github project page and I tried to create an issue there. But then under the issues guide line they specify that you should not create issues for questions, only bug and enhancements. For questions they explicitly mention SO.